# How to begin using SDSS data?

Tags: astronomy, spectroscopy, software, photometry

[SDSS](http://www.sdss.org/) has gone through so many updates, it's difficult to find out how to access the data today in 2015.

How can I use SQL and Python to access SDSS data, e.g. the photometry and spectra of quasars, stars, etc.?

What's the *correct* way to do this today, without using IDL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current data release is DR12. As to how to interact with the data, it depends somewhat on what you want to do. If you have small queries, for instance if you want data for only a handful of objects, there are a couple of web interfaces. If you have larger queries in mind, [CASJobs](http://skyserver.sdss.org/casjobs/) is a good place to start. You'll inevitably need the [schema browser](http://skyserver.sdss.org/dr12/en/help/browser/browser.aspx) to know how the tables are organized.

If you want to run your queries directly from Python, [this tool](http://skyserver.sdss.org/dr2/en/help/download/sqlcl/default.asp) may be useful.

If you know exactly what you're after (plate ID, etc.) you can [go download](http://data.sdss3.org/sas/dr12/) the FITS files directly.

[This page](http://www.sdss.org/dr12/data_access/) and [this page](http://www.sdss.org/dr12/) are good starting points with links to documentation, interfaces and so forth.

Broadly, there is no "correct" way; it really depends on what you're after. Have a look at the different tools and interfaces and see what works for you. I do agree that using IDL is a "wrong" way, though!